# How to remove red syntax error underline in PyScripter?

Tags: python, pyscripter

The red underline won't disappear, so I can't tell what punctuation I've used.

Comment: Have you tried to copy and paste to another editor?

Comment: I think fixing the syntax error is the way to go.

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: Could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: I couldn't see the punctuation because it was obscured by the red underline, but I fixed it. I was just looking for a way to right click and disable the underline.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply comment the line ## which will remove any syntax checking, then uncomment of course. Personally I don't have any trouble with reading syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

You can disable syntax checking by selecting Tools, Options, IDE options, Editor and unchecking "Check syntax as you type".